# Custom JavaScript variable to get the browser viewport comes up as "not set" for majority of users

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I tried to set to up a Custom JavaScript variable in Tag Manager to get the viewport dimensions of the browser window (not the default Screen Resolution dimension) where it would calculate the inner height and width of the browser window and return it as a string (eg. "1920x1080"). I used the following guides:
https://datadrivenu.com/screen-resolution-browser-size-in-google-analytics-4/#How_to_create_the_browser_size_report_in_GA4
https://www.matthewedgar.net/google-analytics-viewport-or-browser-size/

The summary of the guides are:

1. Set up a custom JavaScript variable in Tag Manager with the given function.
2. Set up a custom tag, set the event to "page_view" and set the created variables as user properties. (The guides above mention it should be set to the "GA4 - Configuration" tag, but in the current version of the Tag Manager, the configuration tag is a Google Tag, not a GA4 event tag).
3. Set the trigger to "All Pages".
4. Set up the custom dimension in GA4 and set the scope to user.

I tested this using the Tag Assistant on a desktop (Ubuntu 22.04) and an iPhone 12 (iOS 17) and it fired as expected and returned the correct viewport sizes.

However, when checking with an Exploration report in GA4, the viewport dimensions came as (not set) for almost 90% of the users. (It has been more than 10 days now)

During this time, I have also tried changing the trigger to the DOM Ready and Window Ready events, changing the event to a custom event, changing the variables from User Properties to Event Parameters in the tag and and set event-scoped custom definitions in GA4. I have been getting similar results more or less (90% comes up as not set whether it is user-based or event-based).

Additional information about the website:
Based in Australia, gets about 40k users a month.

P. S. I have posted the same question on Google Analytics Help and Tag Manager Help communities as well.